# XMPP client with group encryption

Tags: ios, iphone-app, xmpp

I'm looking for a XMPP client for iOS that has

- encryption via OTR, OMEMO or another easy-to-use encryption
- group encryption
- correct handling of logs (so that I can see messages sent from my smartphone on a desktop client)
- option to disable "last seen online"

Comment: I'm not using iOS – but as far as I know there's only one client meeting the OMEMO part reliably: ChatSecure. Other iOS users might correct me on that, my information could be outdated ;)

Comment: @Izzy ChatSecure does not have group encryption, sadly. I've edited the question because I meant OTR **or** OMEMO.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, and good luck! As I wrote, I'm not using iOS. I'm on Android with Conversations, which supports that, and if asked for iOS it's always said "there's ChatSecure only". Let's hope someone comes up with an alternative for you!

Comment: @Izzy I've decided to go with ChatSecure. Out of all the iOS clients, it is by far the most advanced. And it's constantly being updated, which is a good sign that group encryption might be a future feature.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Maybe you [answer your own question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) then? Will be helpful to others in a similar situation ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to go with [ChatSecure](http://chatsecure.org/) for mainly two reasons

- it's still under development with very avid contributors
- it is the only iOS XMPP client listed on the AppStore that supports OMEMO encryption.